# matching ranges in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

In my prog I need to, using sed, replace some characters with one another one in some file. But between some words and only if this string contains some extra word. So I wrote:

```
sed -re '/from:/,/end/ { /extraword/s/[_old_characters_]/new_character/g; }'
```

But this code totaly ignors this `/from:/,/end/` strings. It replaces all `[_old_characters_]` with `new_character` starting from `from:` and to the end of this line. What have I done wrong?

What I need is:

```
sed -re '/A/,/B/ { /word/s/[C]/X/g; }'
```

file:

```
word CCC A CCC B CCC
wor A CCC B
```

becomes:

```
word CCC A XXX B CCC
wor A CCC B
```

Comment: what? `/from:/,/end/` means from the first line containing `/from:/` pattern to the first line containing `/end/` pattern execute the block followed. if it's not what you want, state you question clearly with an example or two.

Comment: you code means from the first line containing `/from:/` pattern to the first line containing `/end/` pattern, in every line having `extraword`, do this substitution `s/[_old_characters_]/new_character/g`.

Comment: Are `from:` and `end` on the same line in the input?

Comment: @TomFenech Yes, but this file can contain not only one such string

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I mean that file can contain a lot of strings with word `from` and word `end` and it also can contain `extraword`. And if (and only if) this string contains this `extraword`, I need to replace `[_old_characters_]` with `new_character` starting in the position of word `from` (in this line) and to the `end` (also in this line).

Comment: @Dima so you totally misunderstand the usage of `/from:/,/end/`. your code does what i described.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I added example

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I guess so

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/word/{:a;/(A)([^ABC]*C+[^ABC]*)(B)/{s//\1\n\2\n\3/;h;y/C/X/;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/;ba}}' file
```

This filter lines which contain the word `word` and `A` followed by `C` followed by `B`. Such lines then have markers (`\n`'s) placed after `A` and before `B` and a copy of the line is placed in the hold space (HS). All `C`'s are replace with `X`'s and then the copy in the HS is appended to the amended line and the required line is rebuilt from both. The new line is then tested again and if necessary the procedure is repeated.

If `A` and `B` are words then use the same technique but substitute `\n` after `A` and before `B` first, then test for `/\n.*C.*\n/` remembering to remove all `\n`'s if the condition is not met.

Answer (score 1):

In case using `sed` proves too ugly, here's a `Perl` solution:

```
$ perl -pe 'if (m/word/) {s/(A[^C]*) (.*) ([^C]*B)/$1 . " " . "X" x length($2) . " " . $3/gei;}'
word CCC A CCC B CCC
word CCC A XXX B CCC
wor A CCC B
wor A CCC B
```

Comment: Although I need solution using sed, thanks a lot for your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
sed '/^word/s/A CCC B/A XXX B/g'
```

eg

```
>>> echo word CCC A CCC B CCC | sed '/^word/s/A CCC B/A XXX B/g'
word CCC A XXX B CCC
```

Comment: But I don't know how many times exactly letter "C" will appear there